# AWS EC2 Ubuntu Firewall is enabled, then i can't connect to EC2 because the ssh is not enabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

i enabled firewall inside the ubuntu, sudo ufw enable, but after that i forgot to enable port 22 or ssh port, and then i restart the EC2 instances. how can you connect to EC2 instances?

how can you connect to EC2 instances?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Ubuntu instance comes with Systems Manager Agent installed. You can attach an IAM role which have SSM permission to the EC2 instance. Once role is attached wait for few minutes then you can login to the server by using system manager and then you can allow port 22 in firewall.

Reference link:
AMI list with preinstalled systems manager agent: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/ami-preinstalled-agent.html

Systems Manager setup: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-prerequisites.html